# Snap-lock connector part identification?

Tags: connector, identification

I'm currently working on a design that requires connection to a peripheral with a snap-lock interface. The part I need on the design is the male 'button' style contact found on electrodes such as those shown below. Ideally I'm looking for a surface mount part equivalent to that connection, however a name of the technology or anything that can point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Button style connector example]

The other half of the connector (the 'socket' that mates with the 'button') can be found on cables like the ones below typically.

[image: Socket style connector example]

The only reference to the connectors themselves I can find is that they are "sewing snap buttons size 3", but I am looking for a professional solderable electrical equivalent (although I'm sure the sewing versions would probably work fine, I think the BOM may look a little strange to my colleagues...).

Any information that can be found would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Snap-to-wire, or Snap-to-PCB?

Comment: @Nick Snap-to-PCB

Comment: I once was looking for it too. In the end i used an RF connector and modified the ECG cables. For low volume it worked just fine.

Comment: Did you got the part number of the connector ?. I am also currently in search for the part number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a surface mount part equivalent to that connection

Solder a textile snap-button to the board. You can get them at any craft store that sells sewing supplies. That's how everyone I know does it for eletrophysiology hobby projects, and even for commercial prototyping. For a product, you'd have to probably have these custom made with a coating that makes sense for the intended application, a more hermetic design that won't pass liquids through the button, etc.